# URL Rewriting - .htaccess apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I am using a script from the internet and i get the following URL generated:

`http://mydomain.net/pages/92/Marketing-Idea`

And I want it to look the following:

`http://mydomain.net/marketing-idea`

I'm noob with the URL rewriting, so after looking up for some tutorials I've tired the following rule / condition but it doesn't work at all:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /pages/$1/$2    [NC,L]    # pages
```

Any one that could help me? I'm desperate here and can't get this crap to work!!

This is the entire .htaccess file as it is:

```
#SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /pages/$1/$2 [NC,L]
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_expires.c>    
ExpiresActive On    
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"  
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"   
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"   
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds" 
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|jpg|png|gif|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|cache)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Best Regards,
Dorian

Comment: There is no way to recover the `92` from `marketing-idea`. So, this cannot work at all without an additional database or some lookup table.

Comment: @user2966407 Deleted my answer until I get some clarity. If you want to use: `http://mydomain.net/92/marketing-idea` as pretty URL then I can modify my answer.

Comment: Guys, yes, that would also work. I'm fine with http://mydomain.net/92/marketing-idea

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /pages/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: anubhava, Thank you but this didn't work either. I'd like to mention that lines: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d are already in the .htaccess file

Comment: Can you post your complete current .htacess in your question?

Comment: I've just pasted the enitre .htaccess file. Thanks!

Comment: What URL did you enter? Is it `http://mydomain.net/92/marketing-idea`? Also is there any CMS/PHP framework in place?

Comment: Yeah, tried to enter that URL and 404 error pops. Yes there is a CMS based on a PHP application :/

Comment: Does `/pages/` is framework controlled? And is there another .htaccess inside `/pages/`